# UIImageView focus effect

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, uiimageview, uiblureffect

Does anybody know how to add focus effect to UIImageView so background will be a little bit blurred. Below is an example image

[image]

Image Source: http://cdn-media-2.lifehack.org/wp-content/files/2011/09/focus1.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i just developed one demo project using [CLImageEditor](https://github.com/yackle/CLImageEditor) in Objective-C. You can download my demo for your use from https://github.com/nitingohel/NGFocusView

RunTime output is:

[image]

Comment: Is there Swift version?

Answer (score 1):

You should UIBlurEffect.

```
var vEffect = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .Light))    
vEffect.frame = imageView.bounds
imageView.addSubview(visualEffectView)
```

Comment: It blurs so much that image cannot be recognized. Is it possible to control blur value?

Comment: You can change the style.  There is `.ExtraLight` and `.Dark`

Comment: They produce the same effect image cannot be seen

Comment: As far as I know that is the only built-in API for doing this.  Perhaps what you could do is duplicate the image and blur the one on top, then set its alpha to 0.5 or similar.  That way you would still see the original image through the blurred one and that might be enough to get what you're looking for.

Comment: I tried changing alpha but it only changes color not blur

Comment: Alpha changes the opacity.

Answer (score 1):

Found this one in GitHub. "You can use blur effect and it's animation easily to call only two methods."
https://github.com/marty-suzuki/SABlurImageView

Comment: your question about focus and you put your answer about just making of blur view its not related to your OP.